# If $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices, how to show that: $(A+BB^T)^{-1}B = A^{-1}B(I+B^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

The best I could come up with is 
$$
LHS = (AB^{-1}+BB^TB^{-1})^{-1}
$$

$$
RHS = (B^{-1}A+B^{-1}AB^TAB^{-1})^{-1}
$$

Comment: Just apply $()^{-1}$ to both sides, then use $(MN)^{-1}=N^{-1}M^{-1}$

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulation of the left and right sides has a mistake. Recall that
$$(UV)^{-1} = V^{-1} U^{-1}$$
so in particular, the order of the matrices has to be reversed. As such, the left-hand side is actually
\begin{align*}
  (A + B B^T)^{-1} B &= (B^{-1} A + B^{-1} B B^T)^{-1} \\
&= (B^{-1}A + B^T)^{-1}
\end{align*}
and rewriting the terms on the right side will give the same expression.

Comment: "and rewriting the terms on the left side will give the same expression." You mean the right side, right?

Comment: Whoops! Yep, thanks. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the inverses in the target identity exist in the first place (they won't if $A=-I$ and $B=I$, for example) you can just cross-multiply to get rid of the inverses
 $$(A+BB^T)^{-1}B = A^{-1}B(I+B^TA^{-1}B)^{-1} \\ \iff \\
B(I+B^TA^{-1}B) = (A+BB^T)A^{-1}B $$
and each sides of this simplifies to $B+BB^TA^{-1}B$.